# How do I implement c++ unit testing with googletest in Xcode 4.6?

Tags: c++, xcode, unit-testing, xcode4.6, googletest

I am strougling to set up c++ unit testing with googletest for Xcode 4.6. The instructions that come with the download of googletest were written in 2008 and don't correspond to the current Xcode interface. I *think* I got googletest to compile (which wasn't trivial,) but now I am having issues following [this](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/XcodeGuide#Get_the_Source) tutorial to get a unit test to work. How do I implement unit testing with googletest in Xcode 4.6?

Comment: What have you tried? What are errors? Add more details. As it is, the question is a perfect candidate to be closed as too broad

Comment: This may be helps to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147000/what-is-the-proper-way-to-configure-googletest-with-xcode-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have already got the gtest framework to compile its actually not that hard anymore.

Write your testcases using the macros as described here: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/primer.md#simple-tests

And then to run all your tests:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, (char**)argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I've created a seperate build-target for Unit tests where this is the actual main.cpp
This works for me using the current Xcode version (4.6.3)

Comment: I won't be able to test this until monday, but since the bounty is running out in two hours and no-one else answered, I'll just accept your answer now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you need, i can send you a demo project where everything is set up to work on monday

Comment: @MeXx : Hi, may I get the demo project if its still available please...? Thank you so much.

Comment: @MeXx I have built the library but I cannot find where it is on my machine so I can link my project with it.  Where does the gtest.framework end up after being built?  I followed these videos [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWnoYdxTtL4] and when he builds the gtest project a build directory appears in the project root but for me that is not the case.

Comment: @ddelnano That depends on how your Xcode is set up, you can change the build location in the settings. Or you can just look under the "Products" group in the Xcode Project Navigator. You should see the gtest.framework there. Right-Click on it, "Show in Finder" and there it is.